# Parsing PowerShell script with AST

Tags: powershell, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to parse through a Pester script and extract values from the `-Tag` parameter. Anyone know how to do this using `[System.Management.Automation.PSParser]`?. I'm was thinking I'd have to loop through the tokens returned from `[System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize()` but that seems pretty kludgy and given that the values for `-Tag` could be given in many different formats, not very practical.

At the end of the day, I'm hoping to return a collection with the `Describe` block name, and the list of tags (if any) for that block.

```
Name     Tags        
----     ----        
Section1 {tag1, tag2}
Section2 {foo, bar}  
Section3 {asdf}      
Section4 {}
```

Here are the sample Pester tests that I'm working with.

```
describe 'Section1' -Tag @('tag1', 'tag2') {
    it 'blah1' {
        $true | should be $true
    }
}
describe 'Section2' -Tag 'foo', 'bar' {
    it 'blah2' {
        $true | should be $true
    }    
}
describe 'Section3' -Tag 'asdf'{
    it 'blah3' {
        $true | should be $true
    }
}
describe 'Section4' {
   it 'blah4' {
        $true | should be $true
   }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Is `[System.Management.Automation.PSParser]` the right way to go or is there a better way?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using PS3.0+ [Language namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.language.aspx) AST parser:

```
$text = Get-Content 'pester-script.ps1' -Raw # text is a multiline string, not an array!

$tokens = $null
$errors = $null
[Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($text, [ref]$tokens, [ref]$errors).
    FindAll([Func[Management.Automation.Language.Ast,bool]]{
        param ($ast)
        $ast.CommandElements -and
        $ast.CommandElements[0].Value -eq 'describe'
    }, $true) |
    ForEach {
        $CE = $_.CommandElements
        $secondString = ($CE | Where { $_.StaticType.name -eq 'string' })[1]
        $tagIdx = $CE.IndexOf(($CE | Where ParameterName -eq 'Tag')) + 1
        $tags = if ($tagIdx -and $tagIdx -lt $CE.Count) {
            $CE[$tagIdx].Extent
        }
        New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
            Name = $secondString
            Tags = $tags
        }
    }
```

> ```
> Name       Tags             
> ----       ----             
> 'Section1' @('tag1', 'tag2')
> 'Section2' 'foo', 'bar'     
> 'Section3' 'asdf'           
> 'Section4'
> ```

The code doesn't interpret the tags as a list of strings, but simply uses the original text `extent`.
Use the debugger in PowerShell ISE / Visual Studio / VSCode to inspect the various data type cases.

Comment: Thanks @w0xx0m. With a little modification I was able to pull out the tags as either a [string] or [string[]].